# update segment of a hash in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a hash like so:

```
fields = {
  '0' => {
    'field' => 'something',
    'field_type' => 'something type',
    'validation' => { 'enabled' => 'true', 'persisted' => 'false', 'another thing' => 'false' }
  },
  '1' => {
    'field' => 'something else',
    'field_type' => 'something else type',
    'validation' => { 'enabled' => 'true', 'persisted' => 'false' }
  }
}
```

In the hash above, the boolean values are strings. I want them to be booleans. Also there could be
many key/value pairs but the values will always be either 'true' or 'false'. This is my solution:

```
fields
 => {"0"=>{"field"=>"something", "field_type"=>"something type", "validation"=>{"enabled"=>"true", "persisted"=>"false", "another thing"=>"false"}}, "1"=>{"field"=>"something else", "field_type"=>"something else type", "validation"=>{"enabled"=>"true", "persisted"=>"false"}}} 
 copy = fields.reduce({}) do |acc,(k,v)|
   acc[k] = {
     'fields' => v['field'],
     'field_type' => v['field_type'],
     'validation' => v['validation'].reduce({}) {|acc,(k,v)| acc[k] = (v == "true" ) ? true : false; acc; }
   }
   acc
 end
  => {"0"=>{"fields"=>"something", "field_type"=>"something type", "validation"=>{"enabled"=>true, "persisted"=>false, "another thing"=>false}}, "1"=>{"fields"=>"something else", "field_type"=>"something else type", "validation"=>{"enabled"=>true, "persisted"=>false}}}
```

It works, but my hunch is it is slow and buggy. Is there a more efficient way to do this, perhaps inline (without creating a copy)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will modify the hash inline:

```
fields.each do |record, data|
  data.each do |field, value|
    next unless value.is_a?(Hash)
    value.each do |subkey, subvalue|
      fields[record][field][subkey] = subvalue == 'true'
    end
  end
end
```

Basically, just loop through each hash but store the key at each nesting level so you can directly assign the value in the innermost loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which can deal with ***any hash structure*** no matter what the hash looks like:

```
def convert_boolstring_to_boolean(hash)
  return if hash.class != Hash
  hash.each_pair do |k, v|
    convert_boolstring_to_boolean(hash[k]) if v.class == Hash
    hash[k] = (v == "true") if ["true", "false"].include?(v)
  end
end

convert_boolstring_to_boolean(fields)

puts fields.inspect
```

It recursively try to deal with each sub-hash and convert bool string to bool.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that values of the hashes that are the values of the key `validation` may contain any values, not just `'true'` and `'false'`. Assuming you want to mutate `fields`, you could do it like so:

```
convert = { 'true' => true, 'false' => false }
convert.default_proc = ->(_,k) { k }

fields.each { |_,v| v.each { |_, vv|
  vv.each_key { |kkk| vv[kkk] = convert[vv[kkk]] } if vv.is_a? Hash } }
  #=> {"0"=>{"field"=>"something", "field_type"=>"something type",
  #          "validation"=>{"enabled"=>true, "persisted"=>false,
  #          "another thing"=>false}},
  #    "1"=>{"field"=>"something else", "field_type"=>"something else type",
  #          "validation"=>{"enabled"=>true, "persisted"=>false}}}
```